# Exporting and then importing .dat file elsewhere, then plotting the data

Tags: plotting, export, import

I'm trying to perform a simple task: export data into a '.dat' file, then importing that file onto Mathematica on another terminal, and then plotting the list. But I keep getting the same blank plot!

For example, my export command looks like:

```
Export["Data1.dat",Data1,"Table"]
```

Then I use:

```
DATA = Import["Data1.dat", "Table"];

x = DATA[[All, 1]];
y = DATA[[All, 2]];

data = Transpose[{x, y}];

ListPlot[data, Mesh -> All]
```

Is there a subtlety in what I export?

Comment: Here is the link to the Data1 file:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_7kWMZ0x15g8Zi6V2XjeE5VCNQOQ?e=wrmoyO

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Maybe try restarting with a new Kernel? Another thing you can try is to create a small table of data with the same shape as your large data file and check to see if the format is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers in your file are written as strings.

```
data = Import["Data1.dat", "Table"];

ListPlot[ToExpression@data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be a simple solution.